# Anchor tests not connecting to localhost:8899

Tags: rust, anchor, rust-cargo, solana

I ran an anchor init, anchor build, and then deployed.

I ran "anchor run test" I keep getting this error even though my local validator is running.
What gives?

Error:

Is initialized!:
Error: failed to get recent blockhash: FetchError: request to http://localhost:8899/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8899

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me when I had a different shell running the validator vs the tests. The test can't connect to localhost:8899 if it is already in use. Close the other instance, then run 'anchor test', which will start a local validator and use it for the tests.

Answer (score 0):

When you get "connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8899" error, try using node 16 instead of 17 if you're on 17.

When you get "can't connect to localhost:8899 if it is already in use", try

> anchor test --skip-local-validator